# Cosmos Graph DB auto-failover when using region-specific Gremlin API endpoints?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

Following the advice in [this](https://medium.com/@jayanta.mondal/cosmos-db-graph-gremlin-api-how-to-configuring-preferred-read-write-regions-with-gremlin-clients-69cb4c3db906) article, I have configured my applications to use region-specific Gremlin endpoints so that reads and writes are always directed to the master replica in the same data centre (the Cosmos DB account is multi-master and the applications are deployed to every region on AKS). My question is this: in the event of a regional Cosmos DB outage, what will the behaviour be when using region-specific Gremlin connection strings? Will applications that reference a regional endpoint that is affected by an outage be automatically redirected to a region where the Cosmos replica is healthy?

Answer (score 0):

This depends upon the client SDK the application is using to connect and the connection string logic. If the application [connection string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-graph-dotnet#update-your-connection-string) is pointed to the .NET SDK URI, then you will want to implement either the [.NET SDK v2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-multi-master#netv2) or [.NET SDK v3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-multi-master#netv3) multi-master functionality. If you are using the Gremlin Endpoint, please follow the specific guidance: [Regional endpoints for Cosmos DB for Graph Accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-use-regional-gremlin)

Once that is configured correctly, in the event of an outage, the routing will automatically be redirected to an available write region.